# Minimum switch/router config needed to connect with Ansible

Tags: python, networking, automation, ansible, cisco

So we're considering using Ansible to automate all our network device builds from the point of taking the devices (routers, switches, firewalls) out of thier boxes and racking them, to a fully operational network.

Now, i understand that Ansible connects via SSH which is great however, there must be at least some minimal config on these devices before ansible can connect and configure them.

Does anyone have any idea what the best way to deal with this problem is? Is it a case of manually adding a simple script to each device in order to give it an IP address or is there a more clever (automated) way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some posting on reddit and on the Ansible IRC the Answer is to use Zero Touch Provisioning!

Answer (score -1):

Well you could create a script that writes the basic configs (ip address, ssh connections etc..) and that makes several configs with different ip addresses. Then you simply add it on a USB stick and transfer the appropriate config (ex. SW1 conf or R1 conf) to SW1 or R1. Otherwise I think it's adding it manually which will take a good while if it is a big network with many devices.

Alt. is to make a script as I described and have it uploaded to a FTP server but then again you will manually add these configs and do some pre config. So there is no ultra easy solution sadly (that I know of).

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply. The problem i have with that is. if i'm going to create a basic config why don't i just create the entire config at this point. I realise that i can use Ansible going forward to update devices but really it's just the inital full config i need to get on there. and yes, it's a large enterprise network.

Comment: Well the difference considering it's a large enterprise network would be speed wouldn't it? Im not familiar with ansible but I would guess that it would put out the configs faster then a script would. Especially if it's a full config. I am not sure which would be the most quickest way but personally I would go for a minimal basic preconfig from a script and then let ansible do the job it's intended for.